# Unsupported class file major version 61

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle, dart

при билде приложения идет ошибка [image: сама ошибка]

не знаю как решить проблему, ставил по советам разные sdk сейчас стоит java 8, обновил Gradle до 8.0[image: плагины]
версия androin studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

теперь что то новое:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: См. [How can I fix "unsupported class file major version 60" in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079327/)

Comment: практически все из этого пробывал не помогает @NowhereMan

Comment: Еще вариант для андроид-разработки (январь 2022): [Android Studio Error "Unsupported class file major version 61"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70632741/) -- андроид поддерживает максимум 11 джаву.

Comment: только что пробывал с 11 все тоже самое